# whereIn query does not run in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a query that uses a whereIn clause, but when I deploy it and it gets run by the job it drops this error

```
Error: Value for argument "opStr" is invalid. Acceptable values are: <, <=, ==, >, >=, array-contains, in, array-contains-any
    at Object.validateEnumValue (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:294:15)
    at validateQueryOperator (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2111:16)
    at Query.where (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1013:17)
    at exports.rememberToFinishOrder.functions.pubsub.schedule.timeZone.onRun (/workspace/index.js:168:92)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:127:23)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have read that the error is related to an outdated firebase-admin package, but I have really updated all the things, if I delete the `node_modules` and `package_lock.json` I cant create them again with npm install, what should I do ?

Issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/767

### Query

```
let snap = await db.collection('orders')
                   .where("timestamp","<",new Date(compareDate))
                   .where("status", "in" [1,2,4,5,6]).get()
```

### How I reproduced this

I did a wherein querie and got the error above, searching I have found that the problem is for an outdated version of Firebase Admin, what I have done is the followin

inside the function folder

- npm i firebase-admin@latest
- npm i -g firebase-tools
- npm install --save firebase-functions@latest

none of them worked to update what I need to update to support in queries, then I tried removing the `node_modules` and `package_lock.json` from functions folder, but after I remove them I cant create them again by the followin commands above or by runing

- npm install

inside the function folder

Comment: *"if I delete the node_modules and package_lock.json I cant create them again with npm install"* - why not?  That's the problem you need to explain here,  Please edit the question to be specific about what you're doing.

Comment: I have deleted node_module and package_lock.json from functions folder, if I run npm install tthose files and folders does not create again

Comment: Without seeing the specific steps you're taking here, explained in a way that anyone can duplicate and observe what you see, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: I will be reproducing the problem in my question @DougStevenson

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited my question

Comment: Where do you run those commands?

Comment: in the command prompt inside the functions folder of my function

Comment: I need if I delete those folders to be able to create them again, but I dont know how

Comment: You're saying you don't know how to delete files and folders? Or are you saying you don't know how to recreate them?  `npm install` should do that if it completes successfully.

Comment: yes, the second one, I have deleted them, then trying to recreate them with npm install inside the folder and the node_modules folder is not created and the package_lock.json neither

Comment: Now, I have run sudo npm install and created those folders but the problem persist, I'm really confused

Comment: I get this warning but I dont know if its has something to do npm WARN firebase-functions@3.8.0 requires a peer of firebase-admin@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: That sounds like you're missing a dependency. Something like `npm install --save firebase-admin@^8.0.0` should do the trick. I'd also recommend searching for that error message, as it's quite common.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have done this already multiple times but the error log keeps poping at my console :( I really need this to work but it seems it does not work or update my firebase admin, I'm really confuse

Comment: The error was in the in query, I forgot a , after the IN parameter, wow

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting as Community Wiki, based in the thread of comments in the question. Feel free to modify it and add information as your wish.

Considering the error messages, indeed, it seems related to `firebase-admin` package not being correctly installed with the latest version. For you to install the latest version, you can try one of the following commands:

1. To install directly the version 8.0.0: `npm install --save firebase-admin@^8.0.0`
2. General command to install the latest version: `npm install firebase-admin@latest`

This should help you start fixing your issues.

Thanks @DougStevenson and @FrankvanPuffelen for the insights!